# Twitter stream filter by users with tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I had the following code (simplified) to collect tweets made by users that I follow. But today, the resource `userstream` is deprecated and return the error 410. I would like to keep streaming the tweets made by a list of users that I follow. If I track for anything, like the vowels, than I get the rate limit error.

So, I would really appreciate if anyone knows an alternative to filter tweets by user that don't need to use `userstream`.

```py
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print("Text:", status.text)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

myStream = tweepy.streaming.Stream(api.auth, MyStreamListener())
myStream.userstream(_with='followings')
```

Comment: "If the userstream is no longer available, then i think home_timeline might be the good option.", ref: https://github.com/CruiseDevice/twweet-cli/pull/77#issuecomment-426362626. I tried it and it appears to work

Comment: I've already thought about this option and I'm really considering to migrate for it, but I would like to check if anyone knows some alternative, then I don't need to change all my code structure.